# Python script for outputting vertical rectangles

Tags: python, utf-8, fonts

I'm trying to develop a script to detect those weird vertical in rectangles in a Notepad file. I'm referring to what you can see in the below image:

`![Vertical Rect][1]`

I did try the .encode("utf-8") function as well as utf-18 and utf-32 to try to make the font readable, but received the following error messages for each attempt:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<interactive input>", line
1, in <module> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte
0xef in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Is there any other wide-ranging encoding form that you recommend me try? However, simply being able to output those vertical rectangles in either a notepad TXT file or out in a terminal would be completely acceptable as well. I get the following error message when doing so, however:

```
'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 17-23: character maps to undefined
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are confusing unicode, encodings, characters and fonts. I suggest you read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: Also: Getting those "weird rectangles" and searching for them in your files will get you nowhere. Those rectangles aren't in the text, they are a way for software to indicate that it *can't decode* the text.

Answer (score 0):

You do this like so:

```
>>> import codecs
>>> codecs.decode(b"\xfe\xfe\xff\xff", "utf-8", "replace")
'����'
```

Compare this to:

```
>>> codecs.decode(b"\xfe\xfe\xff\xff", "utf-8")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfe in position 0: invalid start byte
```

You can get more control on data decoding by registering a custom codec, for which see the [codecs documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html)

If the idea is to guess the string encoding to output it correctly, use the [chardet package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet). It's still not that good, so the last resort is to use brute force, and try each available codec in turn (for a list of them, see the above link).

Comment: In its first form, it was a red herring. If the OP copy and pastes those "weird rectangles" and tries to identify files with obscure encodings by searching for them, it will get him nowhere.